# Unable to locate fuse.sh

Tags: jbossfuse

I am new to Jboss-Fuse and was trying to build a sapmle application to get some hands-on on fuse. I was following [JBoss-Fuse documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-fuse/6.3/single/developing-and-deploying-applications/#Develop-CreateWS). I added a user but was unable to start up the container.

According to tutorial to start up the container, I need to run :

```
cd EAPInstallDirectory/bin
./fuse
```

But, I don't see any file with name fuse or fuse.sh.  Only files in bin are :

```
add-user.properties 
appclient.sh 
domain.sh   
fusepatch.log                
fusepatch.sh~                 
jboss-cli.sh   
jdr.sh        
standalone.conf  
wsconsume.sh
add-user.sh          
client        
fuseconfig.sh  
fusepatch-logging.properties  
init.d                        
jboss-cli.xml  
product.conf  
standalone.sh    
wsprovide.sh
appclient.conf       
domain.conf   
fusepatch.bat 
fusepatch.sh                  
jboss-cli-logging.properties  
jconsole.sh    
run.sh        
vault.sh
```

Note: I have installed using EAP-Installer. I am unable to reach fuse console.
I am simultaneously trying `hawtio` to connect to fuse console,but no luck.

Comment: Did you try `run.sh`?

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat offers JBoss Fuse and JBoss Fuse on JBoss EAP.  The JBoss Fuse product contains the fuse.sh file in the 'bin' directory.  JBoss Fuse is OSGi based, while Fuse on EAP is the JEE offering.

The documentation that your referenced is for the JBoss Fuse product.  JBoss Fuse 6.3 can be found here [JBoss Fuse](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-jboss-fuse/)